# Keyboard hide table cells

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard

I would like to increase the keyboard height use in your code by 30. I have a toolbar over my keyboard. I play around with the code but I couldn't make it work. the toolbar over keyboard hides the last cell. I changed this line of code:

```
if ( offset != -1 ) {
    [self setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.contentOffset.x, offset+30) animated:YES]; // this one
}
```

I works but the rest of the cell don't get center anymore when clicking on it.

Where in your code is the height of the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

For that, first you have take scroll view. And add table view inside the scroll view.

After that, you have set scroll view height accordingly.

Like Below:
[scrlPage setFrame:CGRectMake(scrlPage.frame.origin.x, scrlPage.frame.origin.y, scrlPage.frame.size.width, 361.0-150.0)];
[scrlPage setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrlPage.frame.size.width, 361.0)];
[scrlPage setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 50.0)];

Hope you will get it.

Though let me know in case of any difficulty.

Comment: UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView... and having two scrollviews scrollable (contentSize > bounds.size) in the same direction one inside the other doesn't work

Comment: Your meaning is that, you have added tableview inside the scroll view. You can adjust the height of both table and scroll view.  For manage the height of table, you can do like: (no of rows * height for row). So you will get total height of table view. And if it's too long then you can set the minimum height of table. So that, all rows will be scrollable and viewable.

Comment: Yes but you can just as well adjust the height of the tableview alone. Going from height y to y - keyboard.height + toolbar/tabbar.height without making it any more complex, and then you can scroll either with contentOffset or by row